# Uniform Convergence of $\sin^2 (x +1/n )$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

For $n\geq 1$ and let  $g_n(x) = \sin^2(x+ \frac{1}{n}) , x\in [0,\infty)$ and 
$f_n(x)=\int_{0}^{x}g_n(t)dt$
, then

1. {$f_n(x)$} converges point wise to a function on $[0,\infty)$ , but does not converge uniformly on $[0,\infty)$
2. {$f_n(x)$} does not converge point wise to any function on $[0,\infty)$
3. {$f_n(x)$} converges uniformly to a function on $[0,1]$
4. {$f_n(x)$} converges uniformly to a function on $[0,\infty)$

What  I answered is   {$f_n(x)$} converges uniformly to a function on $[0,\infty)$ because the limit converges to $\sin^2(x)$  which is bounded continuous function

Comment: convergence of $f_n(x)$ in $[0,\infty)$ assures its convergence in $[0,1]$ too.

Comment: You have $x$ as the upper limit and also as variable of integration. Also, the limit doesn't converge, it simply is $\sin^2(x).$

Comment: that means what??

Comment: My last sentence above is just about word usage: Limits don't converge. They either exist or don't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right answer, wrong reason. Yes, the limit function is bounded and continuous, but that does not imply the convergence is uniform. For example, $f_n(x) = x/n$ converges pointwise to $0$ on $[0,\infty),$ but the convergence is not uniform there ($\sup_{[0,\infty)} |f_n| = \infty$ for all $n$).

Hint to see that $\int_0^x \sin^2(t+1/n)\,dt$ converges uniformly to $\int_0^x \sin^2(t)\,dt$ on $[0,\infty):$

$$\int_0^x \sin^2(t+1/n)\,dt = \int_{1/n}^{x+1/n} \sin^2(t)\,dt.$$

Comment: The continuity of $\sin^2$ in fact plays no part - you could replace $\sin^2$ with any bounded function with the same conclusion.

Comment: Or in fact, any function which is  $L^p$ for some $p>1$.

Comment: @MasterX Why do you ask about $\int_0^\infty?$ Just compute $ \int_{1/n}^{x+1/n} \sin^2(t)\,dt -  \int_{0}^{x} \sin^2(t)\,dt.$

Comment: ooh I was thinking about we can directly yield it from $\int_{0}^{x} sin^2(t+\frac{1}{n} )$  but why did you used $ \int_{\frac{1}{n} }^{x+ 1/n} sin^2(t+ \frac{1}{n}}   $